# Realm Objective C: No visible @interface for 'RLMObject' declares the selector 'createOrUpdateInRealm:withValue:'

Tags: realm

Cannot figure out why I get this error.

> No visible @interface for 'RLMObject' declares the selector 'createOrUpdateInRealm:withValue:'

I have included the Realm/Realm.h header

Define my RLMObject in this manner

```
Class aClass = NSClassFromString(modelName);
RLMObject *m  = [[aClass alloc] init];
```

Then I create a NSMutableDictionary to contain values which I want to partially update on the RLMObject.

```
NSMutableDictionary *updateValues = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
```

And then I call createOrUpdateInRealm:withValue: on m

```
[m createOrUpdateInRealm:realm withValue:updateValues];
```

But I get the error. I have no idea why this happens?

Answer (score 1):

[`createOrUpdateInRealm:withValue:`](https://realm.io/docs/objc/latest/api/Classes/RLMObject.html#/c:objc(cs)RLMObject(cm)createOrUpdateInRealm:withValue:) should be called on your subclass, not on an instance.

You should use it like this:

```
CustomObject *myCustomObject = [CustomObject createOrUpdateInRealm:realm withValue:dictionary];
```

where `CustomObject` is a subclass of `RLMObject`.

Answer (score 0):

[`+createOrUpdateInRealm:withValue:`](https://realm.io/docs/objc/latest/api/Classes/RLMObject.html#/c:objc(cs)RLMObject(cm)createOrUpdateInRealm:withValue:) is a class method of `RLMObject`, not an instance method. This means you need to call it on your subclass directly, not on an instance of your subclass:

```
[MyClass createOrUpdateInRealm:realm withValue:dictionary];
```